# "Differences IN" vs. "Differences ON"

Tags: prepositions

The usage of "between" and "among" after the singular noun "difference" is quite clear to me. I'd choose the former when contrasting two things and the latter for more than two. 
But, apart from those, it seems to me that the use of "in" and "on" after the plural "differences" is totally optional. Is that right or is there a difference (lol)?

Comment: How would you use 'differences on' in a sentence?

Comment: Hello, Yosef. Here are some examples (using both in and on) taken from a quick Google search:

_[...] **differences on** the Spanish version of the WAIS_ / _Labour and the Tories start to spell out their **differences on** Brexit_ / _Kushner, Bannon sit down to work out **differences on** Trump's orders_ OR _What accounts for the **differences in** their behavior?_ / _To systematically review quantitative **differences in** the control of hypertension_ / _Individual **differences in** perception are ubiquitous within the chemical senses_... And there are many more I could list here.

Comment: It seems from the examples you bring that when the differences are regarding a **topic**, one would say **on**.

Comment: @RiSt, you may have a point here. Actually, what you said has rung a bell, since it made me notice that _behavior_, _control_ and _perception_ are abstract nouns (those which "exist" only through a person's actions). Maybe we're getting closer to something here...

Comment: "Differences on" might also be used in a context like: "There are differences on paper but not in real life."

Comment: @fixer1234, true, but in that case the key verbiage is "on paper".